# Scala Booleans : code snippet

Tags: scala

I'm using some scala code taken from a Scala courers on coursera :

```
package src.functional.week4

abstract class Boolean {

  def ifThenElse[T](t: => T, e: => T): T

  def && (x: => Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(x, false)

}
```

The line  `def && (x: => Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(x, false)` gives this compile time error :

> type mismatch; found : scala.Boolean(false) required:
>   src.functional.week4.Boolean

Here is the code snippet from the video :

[image]

Do I need to change the code in order for it to compile ?

When I create the new 'false' object using

```
  object false extends Boolean {
      def ifThenElse[T](t: => T, e: => t) = e
  }
```

I receive the error :

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - identifier expected but    'false' found.

I am defining the object within the the same class as 'abstract class Boolean'. I am unable to create a new object of type 'false' as the Eclipse IDE does not allow this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code (and Martin's) defines a new `Boolean` even though it's pre-defined / built-in in Scala.

The problem you're encountering is that you have not defined a new `false` to supercede the built-in `false` and the built-in `false` is not compatible with your re-defined `Boolean`.

Comment: yes, I should have watched the rest of the lecture before posting a question. thanks. I have now declared a new 'false' object tbut im getting a new error. I should not be able to create a new object of type 'false' since 'false' is reserved ? I have updated my question

Comment: Scala has a notation for re-defining reserved symbols (primarily to allow interoperation with Java which does not have the same set of reserved words). To (re-) define a reserved symbol, enclose it in back-ticks (both when defining _and_ when referencing it... kinda' tedious, I know).

Answer (score 4):

The code in the lecture does not compile because `true` and `false` are reserved words and can't be redefined. Try using `True` and `False` instead.

Comment: Also it's possible that the lecture dismissed too easily the fact that you also need to define those 2 subclasses (as objects) for `Boolean`... `True` will define `ifThenElse` to return `t` and `False` to return `e`.